# Maze generation prim algorithm not all cells are traversed

Tags: java, algorithm, prims-algorithm

I'm trying to implement Prim maze generation algorithm:

- Start with a grid full of walls.
- Pick a cell, mark it as part of the maze. Add the walls of the cell
  to the wall list.
- While there are walls in the list:

  - Pick a random wall from the list. If the cell on the opposite side
    isn't in the maze yet:

    - Make the wall a passage and mark the cell on the opposite side as
      part of the maze.
    - Add the neighboring walls of the cell to the wall list.
  - If the cell on the opposite side already was in the maze, remove the
    wall from the list.

Removing some implementation details my implementation looks like this:

```
Cell[][] maze
```

is the matrix with cells. each cell has left/right/up/button walls. the frontiers walls marked as `boolean frontier` and are not part of implementation because I want to keep my maze framed.

```
public Cell[][] prim(){
    List<Wall> walls = new ArrayList<Wall>();

    //Pick a cell, mark it as part of the maze
    int initialCellI = rnd(sizeX)-1;
    int initialCellJ = rnd(sizeY)-1;
    Cell randomCell = maze[initialCellI][initialCellJ];
    randomCell.setPartOftheMaze(true);

    //Add the walls of the cell to the wall list.
    if ((randomCell.getLeft() != null) && (!randomCell.getLeft().isFrontier()))
        walls.add(randomCell.getLeft());
    if ((randomCell.getRight() != null) && (!randomCell.getRight().isFrontier()))
        walls.add(randomCell.getRight());
    if ((randomCell.getButtom() != null) && (!randomCell.getButtom().isFrontier()))
        walls.add(randomCell.getButtom());
    if ((randomCell.getUp() != null) && (!randomCell.getUp().isFrontier()))
        walls.add(randomCell.getUp());

    //While there are walls in the list:
    while (!walls.isEmpty()){

        //Pick a random wall from the list.
       Wall randomWall = randomElement(walls);
       //pick the cell opposite to this wall. 
       Cell opositeSideCell = getNeightbourCell(randomWall, maze);
       if (opositeSideCell.isPartOftheMaze()){
           //If the cell on the opposite side already was in the maze, remove the wall from the list.
           walls.remove(randomWall);
       }
       else{
          // Make the wall a passage and mark the cell on the opposite side as part of the maze.
           this.removeWall(randomWall, maze);
           opositeSideCell.setPartOftheMaze(true);

            //Add the walls of the cell to the wall list.
            if ((opositeSideCell.getLeft() != null) && (!opositeSideCell.getLeft().isFrontier()))
                walls.add(opositeSideCell.getLeft());
            if ((opositeSideCell.getRight() != null) && (!opositeSideCell.getRight().isFrontier()))
                walls.add(opositeSideCell.getRight());
            if ((opositeSideCell.getButtom() != null) && (!opositeSideCell.getButtom().isFrontier()))
                walls.add(opositeSideCell.getButtom());
            if ((opositeSideCell.getUp() != null) && (!opositeSideCell.getUp().isFrontier()))
                walls.add(opositeSideCell.getUp());   
       }
    }
    return maze;
}
```

My problem is that my maze is not completed and not all cells are traversed. 
Sometimes a few cells only traversed, almost all cells are done. I believe I'm missing something bur can't figure out what.

Please help.

See picture below for partial traversed maze.

[image]

Comment: Reminds me of a C++ project :)

Comment: @D3mon-1stVFW especially ajax based client side :)

Comment: Is it possible that there is a bug in the isFrontier code, and that the maze is only partially traversed because isFrontier is returning True more often than it should?

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz, I don't believe so, because isFrontier is just getter and boolean frontier has default value false.

Comment: Hmm, in that case I would check your getLeft,getRight, etc. implementation very carefully.  You have no upward or leftward paths in your maze so I suspect that these functions return the wrong answers and this means that your maze can only grow right and below the initial seed point.  Perhaps you could post the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I solved this issue. 
This pure Java issue and has nothing to do with algorithm. I compared between two walls.

```
public class Wall{

    Point p1;
    Point p2;
    }

    public class Point{
    int x;
    int y;
    }
```

If I implement Wall class equals() and hashCode() using p1 and p2. then in 
leftCell.rightWall will be equal to rightCell.leftWall and it was the problem.