# Generate a Maze Java Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

[image]

Imagine the upper 2D World.

You start at 0 and want to go to 6. You have to visit the numbers in that order. You may only step left-right-up-down.

**Question / Algorithm:**
What is the worst case maze (making you walk the most) considering you always choose the optimal path?

Everything Red can't be a Maze-Wall, you can walk on that, and you have to step on the Numbers.

Anything that will help is appreciated. It does not have to be java specific at first... Thank you :)

[image]

The Image above shows some green walls. I doubt that walking every cells once is the longest path. It is easy to make the macerunner walk the same cells a few times.

Comment: Are you asking for someone to provide you with the algorithm to generate the longest path? I can already tell you know the worst outcome is to walk on every cell/square once. That is assuming you can only walk on them once. If not then it is infinity.

Comment: Why are some squares red?

Comment: @Emz if it was infinity then there wouldn't be a valid path through the maze

Comment: @Jonas Shinaniganz Wouldn't the 'worst' possible path just be a single line going around as much as the map as possible?

Comment: Everything Red can not become a Wall, and you can (must) step on it.
-> must, in case it is one of the numbers

Comment: The 4 was just a mistake, added it to the Question.

Comment: @Emz
You can walk on cells multiple times, but you would not do that, unless the mace forces you to take the same path again, because of the order of the cells you have to reach. I strongly disagree with you, if you want i can give an example hand made maze.

Comment: Why do people downvote this great question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your description is kinda confusing since you are not addressing what your needs are in detail, however,
I stronly suggest you to go through [Astrolog.org](http://www.astrolog.org/labyrnth/algrithm.htm) and check all the proposed Maze Algorithms.

Generally speaking, if you need to build a "hard" solving maze algorithm, you can implement [Prim's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_generation_algorithm) and add few circles (by removing a certain amount of walls) to make it harder to solve.

When it comes to solving the maze, there are [several algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maze_solving_algorithm) like Tremaux's, Pledge's and so on. It really depends on whether you are going to implement a Perfect or non-Perfect maze.

A Prim maze generation implementation in [java](/questions/tagged/java) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18242689/prims-algorithm-for-generating-a-maze-getting-the-neighbour-cell) and [here](http://jonathanzong.com/blog/2012/11/06/maze-generation-with-prims-algorithm).